# Русский шрифт для pax s80

Tags: c, terminal

Здравствуйте, где можно найти библиотеку русского шрифта для pax s80? Или как настроить симулятор, чтобы он выводил русские буквы?
Подключила FontLibRussia(V12).bin, как советовали ниже, но он ничего не выводит.
Например нужно вывести

```
ScrPrint(0, 1, 0, "Привет мир!");
```

ничего не выводит, если писать английским шрифтом, то работает нормально

```
 ScrPrint(0, 1, 0, "Hello world!");
```

Answer (score 1):

По [ссылке](https://qiwi.com/business/agents/files/QIWIPos_PAX_AdminGuide.pdf) инструкция по настройке от Qiwi, там на на третьей странице ссылка на русский шрифт `FontLibRussia(V12).bin`. Должно помочь.

Comment: спасибо за ответ. Подключаю библиотеку FontLibRussia(V12).bin, но он ничего не выводит.